# SQL query to insert an additional calculated field within the select statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-2007

Your help would be much appreciated. I'm trying here to extract data coming from a selected workbook via a GETOPENFILENAME to access "Data$" worksheet and select all the data and add an extra calculated field based on 2 conditions, that one of the fields its date is earlier or equal to a defined string which is v(1st day of the month) in my SQL string and the other filed its type is an invoice, then the new filed is outstanding. please see the piece of code I'm having.

```
     With connection
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Vfile& ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
       End With
        sql= "SELECT T1.* " & _
     ",IIF(T1.[Due Date] <= '" & v & "' " & _
    "AND T1.[Type] ='Invoice'),T1.[Outstanding] AS [InvValue]) " & _
     "FROM [Data$A1:Z100000] T1"
      Set Rs = connection.Execute(sql)
```